# Paginación con Swift

Tags: swift, funciones, paginación

a ver si me pueden ayudar un poco. O sea realmente no soy muy bueno con las matemáticas y por eso necesito algunas ideas.

Tengo que consumir un endpoint rest, que me devuelve por ejemplo que el esta brindando información de 1624 elementos. El tema es que yo puedo pedir esos elementos de 100 en 100, o sea del 1..100, 101.200, ...... 1600..1624.

En fin, lo que necesito es ayuda de como implementar una funcion a modo de utilidad que cuando yo le pase como parametros que tengo 1624 elementos y que los puedo consumir de 100 en 100, ella me devuelva un array o diccionario donde contenga algo como esto:

[1, 100]
[101, 200]
[201, 300]
.....
[1600, 1624]

Algo así realmente me seria de muchísima ayuda. Gracias por adelantado.

PD: Utilizo Swift 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtener la respuesta que buscas de esta forma:

```
var pages = [[Int]]()
let totalItems = 1624
let pageSize = 100
let segments = totalItems / pageSize

for i in 0...segments {
    let step = i * pageSize
    let start = step + 1
    let end = step + pageSize
    pages.append([start, min(end, totalItems)])
}

print(pages)
```

No obstante yo te recomendaría que optaras por un enfoque a nivel de la API de rest e implementar la paginación allí. Así, si el usuario finalmente no quiere ver los 1624 items, porque tendríamos que descargarlos todos?.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Justamente algo como esto era lo que estaba buscando. Ya si cualquier otro detalle yo mismo lo adapto. Por el momento tengo que descargar todos los elementos, como requisito del app, pero el API es privada y solo puedo obtener los datos de esa forma.

Comment: De nada, un placer!

Answer (score 0):

Para ese tipo de problema mi recomendación es que en tu api hagas esta modificacion : pide como parámetros números de paginas ejemplo :
/////////---API----//////////////
"pagina" : 0
/////////////////
en tu servicio claro haces la validación si te retorna la "pagina" : 0 le devuelves un array de 0 a 100 , si te retorna "pagina" : 1 le devuelve un array de 101 a 200, etc.

ahora cuando listes tu array en un tableView o CollectionView puedes usar eventos del scroll para que cuando llegue al objeto final cargues el servicios y ese array que te devuelve el servicio lo iguales a tu array principal y le haces un reladDAta a tu tableView